# (Xtext) How to change the scoping of imported resources via importURI?

Tags: xtext

I have a DSL that allows to explicitly import resources (via `importURI` attribute). Everything is working just fine, except the fact that I would like to refer to imported elements directly by their ID (not by fully qualified name).

I am not using `importedNamespace`, because I've limited the GlobalScope to only what is explicitly imported and for each resource I need all elements (like *ModelName*.*).

So, right now I'm able to refer to imported elements like this:
*ModelName*.*OuterElement*.*InnerElement*
but I would like to have something like this:
*OuterElement* or *InnerElement*.

Of course, the general context is more complex and a bit different, but I've tried to simplify everything just around this question. So, please refer to the following grammar:

```
Model:
  name=ID ':'
  (include+=Include)?
  (outerElems+=OuterElement ';')*
  (uses+=Use ';')*;

Include:
  'import' importURI=STRING ;

OuterElement:
  'def' name=ID
  '(' (innerElements+=InnerElement (',' innerElements+=InnerElement)* )? ')' ;

InnerElement:
  name=ID;

Element:
    OuterElement | InnerElement;

Use:
  'use' use =[Element|FQN];

FQN:
    ID('.'ID)* ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to refer to elements by their simple name you have to bind

```
SimpleNameProvider
```

as `IQualifiedNameProvider`

```
public Class<? extends IQualifiedNameProvider> bindIQualifiedNameProvider() {
    return SimpleNameProvider.class;
}
```

respectively

```
override bindIQualifiedNameProvider() {
    SimpleNameProvider
}
```